# Placing gnomes in garden Python exercise

Tags: python

The task objective:

A gardener has been asked to position gnomes in a garden, There are three colours - green gnomes, red gnomes and yellow gnomes.

You have been asked to work out how many of each colour they will need you cannot split gnomes, you need to only provide a whole number.

You have been advised that the gardener needs to position one gnome every meter squared. Given an integer as x - can you provide how many of each colour of gnome the gardener will need. If x was 3 the gardener would need one gnome of each colour. Adapt the code below, your code should work when x is changed to any number from 1-1000

x = 4

The problem is when I change the value of x to a different number the number of gnomes i.e. the red, green, yellow gnomes doesn't increase. It produces the same answer as the one I calculated for x = 4

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
x = 4

def rgnome(a, b):
    red = a * b
    return red

number_red = rgnome(1, 1) 
    
def ggnome(a, b):
    green = a * b
    return green

number_green = ggnome(1, 1) 

def ygnome(a, b):
    yellow = a * b
    return yellow

number_yellow = ygnome(1, 2)

print ("The number of Red gnomes will be: ", (number_red))

print ("The number of Green gnomes will be: ", (number_green))

print ("The number of Yellow gnomes will be: ", (number_yellow))
```

Comment: If you have 10 square metres, can you just have 10 red gnomes, and 0 yellow and green?

Comment: So, what would be your approach to solving this question? I just want to see other people's methods to see where I went wrong. I'm new to programming.

Comment: Is X the number of square metres? Can you just return X red gnomes? What am I missing here

Comment: Well, according to the question, it isn't really specified if 'X' means square meters; although it might mean that. What I understood form the question is that you need to place one colour of gnome every square meter, and if 'X' - which might mean square meter - was equal to 3 then that means to put one coloured gnome in three individual square meters e.g. a red gnome in the first square meter, green gnome in the second square meter, yellow gnome in the third square meter. But the questions is how many gnomes of each colour you will need to put in each square meter if X was changed to 4.

Comment: So, what I did was basically put a red gnome in the first square meter, a green in the second square meter, and yellow in the third square meter. However, since there's another square meter I added it to the one which has the yellow gnome and now the fourth square meter has two yellow gnomes. However, x should also calculate to number of gnomes if it's changed to any numbers between 1 to 1000 e.g. X = 57 and that's the thing I don't get how to do.  Although my whole program could be wrong from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- X is the number of square metres
- You need to alternate gnome colours, e.g. Red, Green, Yellow, Red, Green, Yellow, Red, ... etc.

Solution:

We want to divide X by 3 to give us the base number of gnomes we need, and then add extra gnomes for any remainder. So

- If X is 10, 10 // 3 == 3 with 1 remaining, so we need 3 of each colour and 1 extra red
- If X is 11, then 11 // 3 == 3 with 2 remaining, so we need 3 of each colour and 1 extra red and 1 extra green.
- If X is 12, then 12 // 3 == 4 with 0 remaining, so we need 4 of each colour.

Code:

```
get_gnomes(x):
    base = x // 3
    remaining = x % 3
    result = {"red": base, "green": base, "yellow": base}
    if remaining in (1, 2):
        result["red"] += 1
    if remaining == 2:
        result["green"] += 1
    return result
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and it all starts to make sense now, but I still have one minor question to ask. When I tested your code and try to implement it into my code I get all sorts of errors. My question is how can I implement your code to print out the number of red, green, and yellow gnomes like in my code above?